# restore database from data only mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where I have a data only mysqldump (probably created with --no-create-info) so all the table create commands in the dump are missing and also the information about the columns are missing. The previous developer neither provided the full dump nor the database. I would like to restore the database, which only consist of numeric values and time stamps. Is there a tool which can restore the tables and their structures as much as possible?

Edit: 
The purpose of the restoration is to be able to make use of a python library to read out the data and process them further (not to make the resulting database operational in the backend). Thus it would be nice to be able to use some sql library to convert the data from the partially restored database into a pandas dataframe. I could of course write some python script with regular expressions to extract the data directly from the dump. However I wondered if there already exist something more elegant to achieve a partial restoration.

An truncated example of the dump would be:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: sensordata
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `humidity`
--

LOCK TABLES `humidity` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `humidity` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `humidity` VALUES (1,25,58),(2,24,58),(3,24,58);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `humidity` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `humidity22`
--

LOCK TABLES `humidity22` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `humidity22` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `humidity22` VALUES (1,25.1,53.4),(2,24.8,53.1),(3,24.8,53.1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `humidity22` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `moisture1`
--

LOCK TABLES `moisture1` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `moisture1` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `moisture1` VALUES (1,0),(2,0),(3,0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `moisture1` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `moisture2`
--

LOCK TABLES `moisture2` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `moisture2` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `moisture2` VALUES (1,0),(2,0),(3,0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `moisture2` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `pressure`
--

LOCK TABLES `pressure` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pressure` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `pressure` VALUES (1,24.7,97326,337.362),(2,24.6,97321,338.136),(3,24.6,97333,337.62);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pressure` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `rain`
--

LOCK TABLES `rain` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `rain` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `rain` VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `rain` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `temperature`
--

LOCK TABLES `temperature` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `temperature` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `temperature` VALUES (1,23.62,NULL,NULL,NULL),(2,23.56,NULL,NULL,NULL),(3,23.56,NULL,NULL,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `temperature` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `timestamp`
--

LOCK TABLES `timestamp` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `timestamp` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `timestamp` VALUES (1,'2018-07-27 09:29:43'),(2,'2018-07-27 09:29:57'),(3,'2018-07-27 09:30:04');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `timestamp` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2018-07-28  0:00:05
```

Comment: do you have access to a programming language ... e.g. Bash/PHP?

Comment: I can use Python in a Linux environment. However it would be nice to not have to write my own code to parse the sqldump

Comment: you can make some educated guesses about the data types of the columns, but I see it doesn't even include the column names in the INSERT statements. So if there's any other code which uses the database, you'd likely break that by using the wrong column names. And it will also be pretty difficult to determine the keys, indexes and other constraints, plus things like triggers might also be missing. All in all, you've got a bit of a problem. I don't think any tool (or human being) could realistically restore anything very accurate from such an incomplete set of information.

Comment: Is there nowhere where this database is currently deployed that you could go to and look at it? Or any historical records in source control, old VM backups, server backup tapes, _anything_ which might give you more info?

Comment: @ADyson I edited the question. My goal is not to make the resulting DB operational but rather to make the data structure accessible via other python libraries, whereas the names of the columns don't matter to much. I want to avoid to write an python parser for my corner case to avoid error prone process of doing so :/

Comment: If you don't want to write a parser then you'll have to manually write some CREATE TABLE statements based on what you think the tables should look like. But aspects of the structure (e.g. relationships between tables) will still be unclear, especially as the data is nearly all numeric. I'm not aware of any tool which would do that for you based on the dump file you've shown (and asking for recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any tool available and  it's impossible to restore data without any information.